# WPF ObservableCollection containing List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf

for some time I am struggling with ObservableCollection containing List. I am not able to get it working in a way, that each List is in its own expander.
You can imagine input data as a list of records per day and each list contains orders for that day.

Here is some code:

**My version 1:**

```
public class Order
{
public string OrderId { get; private set}
}

public ObservableCollection<Order> ObservableResults 
{
    get 
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Order>
        {
            new Order("Foo"),
            new Order("Bar")
        };
    }
}
```

**XAML file:**

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableResults}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order Id" Width="650" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OrderId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    /ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This one worked just fine, but the problem was, that I had all the orders in a single grid view and that's something I did not really like so I wanted to modify it, that I will get List of orders and fill the ObservableCollection with these lists. Pretty much each list represents one day worth of orders. So I have modified the code like this:

**Code behind**

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; private set}
}

public ObservableCollection<List<Order>> ObservableResults 
{
    get 
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Order>
        {
            new List<Order>
            {
                new Order("Foo")
            },
            new List<Order>
            {
                new Order("Bar")
            }              
        };
    }
}
```

But I do have a problem with the XAML part right now... I am not really sure, how to achieve the following:
It will be a single scroll view, where each `List<Order>` will be encapsulated in its own Expander (so I can open close each day individually). So far I have this:

**XAML version 2:**

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Red">
    <ListView Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableResults}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander>
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Order ID" Width="650" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OrderId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But in this case no data are present in the view and the ReSharper says, that it:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'OrderId'

Can anyone help me, what's wrong in here?

Comment: check this : https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/09/25/embedded-expender-control-inside-listbox-in-wpf/

Comment: @GaurangDave This does not really solve my problem. They still use single List<T> as DataSource (instead of ObservableCollection) and the only encapsulated each record in the expander. That's something I can almost do in my first example as well. That's not what I am after. Thank you though

Comment: Why are you not update your `Order` model to containing the inner list? ```public class OrderTopic
{
    public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}```

Comment: Returning a new ObservableCollection from the ObservableResults property getter is a bad idea. Imagine what happens when the getter is called more than once. Besides that, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the DisplayMemberBinding is pointless. It has no effect, and has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Setting itemsouce from back-end (window.cs ) is working for me